# how do I make images fit the browser and resize?

Tags: html, css

I can't find how to make the image fit the browser as it it currently cropping it and resize with the browser

[image: webpage currently]

```
<div class="contentwrapper">
<img src="img/1.%20Self%20Branding%20display2.png">
</div>

.contentwrapper {
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:97vw;
height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: On contentwrapper the 100% doesn't mean of the screen but the containing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using max-width and height.

```html
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```